# Magento 2: Add email date header

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

In mail-tester.com I get 1,5 point lower because of a missing date header in my transaction emails.

How to add the date header in transaction emails?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the SMTP module from mageside and there the headers are set, works fine!